# Rejoining Old Primary Node as Secondary in SQL Server Always On Availability Group Post Forced Failover

Tags: sql-server

Encountering synchronization issues after a forced failover in a three-node SQL Server Always On Availability Group setup.

I am facing a challenge in a SQL Server Always On Availability Group setup with a three-node configuration. Initially, node-1 was the primary node, and nodes-2 and -3 were secondary nodes.

A network failure occurred, causing node-1 to disconnect from the other two nodes. To address this, I performed a forced failover to node-2 using the command ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP AG_NAME FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS. Consequently, node-2 became the new primary node, and write operations continued.

Meanwhile, node-1, unaware of the forced failover, also continued its write operations independently.

Upon recovery from the network failure, attempting to rejoin node-1 to the availability group as a secondary node using the standard commands (ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG_NAME] SET (ROLE = SECONDARY); and ALTER DATABASE [AG_DB_NAME] SET HADR RESUME;) did not resolve the synchronization issue as outlined in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-forced-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#FollowUp:%7E:text=After%20a%20forced%20failover%2C%20all,the%20synchronous%2Dcommit%20secondary%20databases.:%7E:text=After%20a%20forced%20failover%2C%20all,on%20the%20new%20primary%20database.).

While it is acceptable to lose data on the old primary node, I am seeking a solution to rejoin it to the new primary without resorting to a fresh node approach, which involves dropping the entire database. Considering the substantial data size (5-6TB), such an approach is not feasible.

Any recommendations or solutions to address this issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Considering the substantial data size (5-6TB), such an approach is not feasible.

That’s the only way.

If you can't restore a database from a backup you can't operate.  So if this is really "not feasible" you don't have a supportable, production-ready solution.

Operating a 6TB database *requires* infrastructure that can not only handle the normal day-to-day transaction processing, but also can handle these kinds of one-time expensive operations.

Comment: While I'm inclined to agree with you, this feels like a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Clarified that there’s no alternative

Comment: As the full backup restore takes a lot of time, I was looking for an efficient solution to bring the old primary back into the availability group. Like in Postgres, we can synchronize the standby (secondary) replica to the primary replica efficiently using the `pg_rewind` command. 

`pg_rewind` in PostgreSQL allows for the synchronization of a standby server with the primary server without requiring a new base backup.

Answer (score 0):

Since node 1 continued to take writes after node 2 was forced to be the primary instance, you very likely have a forked history scenario. The last thing I'd try before doing a full restore from backups is: can you restore differential/t-log backups (all specifying `norecovery`!) from node 2 onto node 1? If yes, do that until you've restored enough t-log such that node 1 is caught up to node 2. Once that's the case, you should be able to join that database into the AG.

But I suspect that you will not be able to do that. Trying to restore that differential backup will tell you pretty quickly whether you can or not. If not, your only option is to restore the entire database from backups onto node 1.

Lastly, regardless of the path you take, I'd do `alter availability group [«your AG»] remove replica [node1];` while you're doing the restores. Why? As far as node2 is concerned, node1 could come back at any time and is holding t-log for that eventuality. You know better and that it's going to take a long time for that to happen. It's better to remove the replica now so that your active t-log doesn't exhaust your free disk space and add it back in as you're closer to being able to do so (i.e. you've done all the t-log restores you need to do).

Comment: I see, I can not restore a t-log backup or differential backup without restoring a full backup first. I see these errors: 
Msg 3117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The log or differential backup cannot be restored because no files are ready to rollforward.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

Is it possible to restore a t-log backup without restoring a full backup?

Comment: No. As I alluded to above, the state of the database on node1 diverged from that of node2 once you forced failover and node1 continued to take writes. Your only option at this point is to plan a restore that brings the database into a state that is consistent with what is currently on node2. And that will start with restoring a full backup. If I were you, I'd look at `Get-DbaBackupInformation` and `Restore-DbaBackup` from the dbatools powershell module. It's pretty good at examining backups and coming up with a restore solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I see that, I can't join the old primary (node-1) back into the availability group after a force fail-over to (node-2), even though no write operation was performed on any node. So no split-brain / forked history scenario is created. 

When I run  ` ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [ag1] 
     SET (ROLE = SECONDARY);  ` 
the error I get is: 
Msg 41104, 
Failover of the availability group 'AG1' to the local replica failed because the availability group resource did not come online due to a previous error. 
Can I rejoin my old primary  (node-1) in this case?

Comment: I'm confused. From your initial question, "Meanwhile, node-1, unaware of the forced failover, also continued its write operations independently.". But in your above comment, you say that it did (and the attempted restore failing corroborates this). Lastly, from the documentation, the command that you ran is specifically for a distributed AG failover scenario which I doubt applies to you. Adding node1 back to the topology should be an `alter availability group... add replica...` (on primary node) and `alter database ... set hadr availability group...` (on node1). Just like when you created it.

Comment: All of the above taking place after you've done sufficient restore operations on node1 to bring it up to date with the current primary.